The lifcycle of this in c++ async function
I know that in c++ asynchronous functions, its arguments are valid for the duration of its execution. A member method of a class that is also given to an asynchronous function will have this implicitly as its first argument. The problem is that this is a pointer and has no notion of a life cycle. My personal guess is that during its execution, the object itself may be destructed and this may become a wild pointer.

Am I correct in my assumptions above?
How to ensure that this is not destructed during the entire execution of the method. I used to have classes inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this to get the shared_ptr of this, but this has a huge limitation, which requires that this itself must be managed by a shared_ptr.

My usage scenarios are heavily populated with code like
asio::co_spawn(executor, [?] () -> asio::awaitable<void> {
  co_await this->async_method(); 
}, asio::detached);

This results in no guaranteed association of the method's lifecycle with the lifecycle of this. and this is restricted and could not be managed by a shared_ptr

Um...no. The entire point of enable_shared_from_this is, to be able to get a shared_pointer from a raw pointer without having (direct) access to the owning shared_ptr. The instance must be OWNED by a shared_ptr somewhere for ESFT to work.

What is this async function doing? Is it calculating some result that needs to be returned? Then the caller just needs to wait for that result, somewhere in the code that guarantees that the object will not be destructed. Otherwise, do the async function really need this? Why not a copy of *this? Or a copy of the member variables it needs? And if it should be really independent why not create a detached thread instead? The requirements and the use-case are important here for the design and implementation.

To my knowledge async will neither allocate nor deallocate any sort of object. The memory management is handled in your code. Unless the code passed to async deallocates the object explicitely (or your main code does, while async is still running), your object will be safe. However, to ensure that the object stays alive for the duration of async, a shared_ptr seems like your best bet.

A member method of a class that is also given to an asynchronous function will have this implicitly as its first argument. this is not correct, are you passing a lambda in an std::function and the lambda is implicitly capturing this ? if this is the case then that's your bug, you are implicitly capturing a raw pointer that doesn't extend the object's lifetime, and as others have pointed you should be capturing a shared_ptr instead to extend the object lifetime

"that this itself must be a shared_ptr." this makes no sense. shared_ptr does not inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this and you cannot make it so. Perhaps a concrete example could help to make this question more clear.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: I think the (incorrect) assumption is that this would be a shared_ptr<T> instead of a T*. That is dangerously untrue; in particular this does not keep the object alive.

@MSalters My interpretation is that they merely picked the wrong words and mean that this is managed by a shared pointer, but I am not sure, and its a detail too crucial to be overlooked imho

@463035818_is_not_an_ai yes, I mean this is managed by a shared pointer, if not, call weak_from_this only return a null weak_ptr. The code will crash in runtime

you can still [edit] the question to clarify


Am I correct in my assumptions above?

You are correct that there's nothing stopping other code from destroying the object while it has a suspended coroutine member function.

How to ensure that this is not destructed during the entire execution of the method.

The same ways that you ensure one object outlives another. In this case the other object is the coroutine. This can be by ensuring the first object is owned by a shared pointer, and arranging for the second object to hold a shared pointer to the first, but it can also be done in other ways.
If the first object is local to (or owned by something that is) some function that is going to wait for the coroutine to be finished, then it will provably outlive the coroutine. That function might itself be a coroutine, co_awaiting the coroutine in question.

My usage scenarios are heavily populated with asio::co_spawn(executor, [?] () -> asio::awaitable<void> { co_await this->async_method(); }, asio::detached); This results in no guaranteed association of the method's lifecycle with the lifecycle of this. and this is restricted and not managed by shared_ptr

@vipcxj right, but who owns this, when might they destroy it? Passing asio::detached  means that you don't care about knowing when the coroutine has finished, but you do care, you need to know when everything you have started has finished, so the owner of your object is free to destroy it.

Normally I have a mechanism to end the task earlier. But there is no guarantee that the end will be earlier than this destructed. It could be just a few millimeters, or even a few micrometers, in any case there is no guarantee of the sequence. Anyway, this kind of thing is very common. It's just a matter of giving the asynchronous task an end signal. The asynchronous task still need some time to complete itself.

@vipcxj It's on you to ensure this outlives it. "Hope it does" is an invitation to undefined behaviour. That may mean you have to stop using asio::detached instead of a completion handler, or it may mean you have to wrap everything in shared pointers, or it may mean something else. I don't have the context to say what is more appropriate for your situation.
